# Change CSS on specific page only (non wordpress site)

Tags: html, css

I can only change CSS without contacting our developer, so I need to figure this out without editing the HTML.

This page is a category page to other pages. 
http://gorealescapes.com/hensbridal-shower

I would like to hide the text underneath the images. I want to do "display: none" on .ft-foot

The problem is that my product pages uses the same class and i DO want to keep the text there. This is a page with with products. 
http://gorealescapes.com/hensbridal-shower/hensgirls/

Any suggestions how i can do this? I know some sites has page numbers but my page doesn't =o/

Comment: Whatever you do there is some changes required on javascript or html to do that ..

Comment: How are you modifying the CSS without touching the HTML? Is there an existing stylesheet you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Well on the page you're interested in they are using `<p class="CTPContext"></p>` whereas on the other page it's using a `<span>`, but both look the same in terms of styling. You don't have to climb back up to the shared parent class of `ft-foot` when you can just target the element the text is actually in, which in this case would be...

```
.CTPContext {
    display:none;}
```

The problem with this though is it may be used elsewhere, kinda like how `.ft-foot` is used in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility hidden property in css could help assuming that i understood your question. You could create a new class for the text under the images and set the visibility property. Here is a link for some [perspective](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_visibility) . Hope it helps. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you could add a class to the body tag of http://gorealescapes.com/hensbridal-shower and use this to help target elements on just this one page, eg
**HTML**

```
<body class="hensbridal-shower">
   ...
     <h4 class="ft-title text-upper"><a href="/hensbridal-shower/adelaide/">Adelaide</a></h4>
   ...
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.hensbridal-shower h4.ft-title.text-upper{
   display:none;
}
```

Good luck!